# Should I delete or disable an admin users for Magento 2.3 and above

Tags: admin-user

I would like to see the pros and cons of simply deleting an admin user versus disabling an admin user on either Adobe Commerce or Magento Open Source.

Please give the logic for either in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any option to specifically disable an already created admin user.

**Account Options**

- Make the user inactive by setting the user's account expiration date
  to an earlier date
- Assign the user to a role with no role resources
- Manually change the user's password forcing their account to go into
  locked status after 6 failed log in attempts
- Delete the user's account

Worst case, setup of a user account is pretty straight forward...

```
bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user='admin' --admin-password='password' --admin-email='admin@example.com' --admin-firstname='admin' --admin-lastname='admin'
```